# Invision's Craft doesn't place high definition images in Sketch

Tags: images, sketch-app, resize, resolution, image-quality

I'm using Sketch and Invision's "Craft" plugin. If I want to place an image as a fill inside a rectangle I use Craft (which takes the images from Unsplash).

My issue is that these images are being downscaled. For example, Unsplash has a vast collection of very high resolution images. If I want to fill (with an image) a 200x200 pixel rectangle, the image will get downscaled so it can fit the rectangle.

The only solution is to manually download the high resolution photo, make my rectangle a mask and resize the image so it can fit inside.

Is there a way to make the images being placed inside any rectangle high resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is enlarge rectangle (for example 2 times), then use craft and again make rectangle smaller.